# PowerShell: XML to Object

Tags: powershell

I read out data from a XML-File and want to get an object like this:

```
TaskSequenceNumber TaskSequenceName
------------------ ----------------
1                  01_Base
2                  02_ABC
```

The XML-File Looks like this:

```
$xml = [xml]@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeploymentScript>
  <Settings>
    ...
  </Settings>
  <TaskSequences>
    <Sequence1>
      <TaskSequenceNumber>1</TaskSequenceNumber>
      <TaskSequenceName>01_Base</TaskSequenceName>
    </Sequence1>
    <Sequence2>
      <TaskSequenceNumber>2</TaskSequenceNumber>
      <TaskSequenceName>02_ABC</TaskSequenceName>
    </Sequence2>
  </TaskSequences>
</DeploymentScript>
"@

$xml.DeploymentScript.TaskSequences
```

The code above is prepared for easy copy & paste into ISE, if anybody wants to try it.

About the name of the nodes `Sequence1` and `Sequence2` I am not sure yet. Maybe they could be renamed to `$TaskSequenceName` or `$TaskSequenceNumber`.

.

**EDIT:**

I am really sorry, but I need to reopen my request about it.
I was trying to implement the posted solution of Martin, but I came into trouble. Look at the following example:

```
Clear-Host

Function Simple-Test {

    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,position=0)]
        [string]$ControlObject
    )

    $ControlObject | Format-Table

}

$xml = [xml]@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeploymentScript>
  <Settings>
    ...
  </Settings>
  <TaskSequences>
    <Sequence1>
      <TaskSequenceNumber>1</TaskSequenceNumber>
      <TaskSequenceName>01_Base</TaskSequenceName>
    </Sequence1>
    <Sequence2>
      <TaskSequenceNumber>2</TaskSequenceNumber>
      <TaskSequenceName>02_ABC</TaskSequenceName>
    </Sequence2>
  </TaskSequences>
</DeploymentScript>
"@

Simple-Test -ControlObject $xml.DeploymentScript.TaskSequences.GetEnumerator()
```

The script won't work as I would expect. I get the result:

> System.Xml.XmlElement System.Xml.XmlElement

How to correct this?

Thank you!

Comment: Remove `[string]` in line 6

Comment: OMG :-) Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the output by calling the `GetEnumerator()` method:

```
$xml.DeploymentScript.TaskSequences.GetEnumerator()
```

**Output:**

```
TaskSequenceNumber TaskSequenceName
------------------ ----------------
1                  01_Base         
2                  02_ABC
```

Comment: Hah, thats it :-) Thank you Martin!

Comment: Sorry, I came in trouble, when I was trying to implement it. I did edit the request ...